# Android:Local Notification misfires

Tags: android, android-notifications

I am trying to set a daily notification in android. Using alarm receiver following is my code.

```
public class DrawerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_drawer_menu);
        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(DrawerActivity.this, LocalNotificationReceiver.class);
  dailyNotificationPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(DrawerActivity.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

   dailyNotificationManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);



    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    dailyNotificationManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, dailyNotificationPendingIntent);

    }
}
```

This is my alarm receiver

```
public class LocalNotificationReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    private  final static String TAG = "LocalNotificationReceiv";
    public LocalNotificationReceiver(){}
    Realm realm;
    private NotificationUtils notificationUtils;
    String currentStartDate;
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
    public NumberFormat numberFormat =  NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.US);
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        Calendar calStartDate = Calendar.getInstance();

        dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        currentStartDate = dateFormat.format(calStartDate.getTime());

        SweatPointFitnessDB sweatPointFitnessDB = realm.where(SweatPointFitnessDB.class)
                                                    .equalTo("forday",currentStartDate)
                                                    .findFirst();

        String title;
        String alert;

        try{
            if (sweatPointFitnessDB.getStepCount() != 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Yout step count today notification: " + sweatPointFitnessDB.getStepCount());
                title = "Hey you did " + numberFormat.format(sweatPointFitnessDB.getStepCount()) + " steps today!!";
                alert = "Kudos";

            } else {
                title = "You were inactive today!!";
                alert = "Buckle up";
            }



            Log.i(TAG, "inside local notification receiver");
            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            showNotificationMessage(context, title, alert, resultIntent);

        }catch (Exception e){

        }




    }


    private void showNotificationMessage(Context context, String title, String message, Intent intent) {

        notificationUtils = new NotificationUtils(context);

       // intent.putExtras("title",title);


        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        notificationUtils.showNotificationMessageNew(title, message, intent);
    }

}
```

Finally this is my notification activity.

```
 public void showNotificationMessageNew(String title, String message, Intent intent){
            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(message)){
                return;
            }


                int icon = R.drawable.push_icon;

                int mNotificationId = 100;

                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                        PendingIntent.getActivity(
                                mContext,
                                0,
                                intent,
                                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT
                        );

                NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =  new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();

                NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);
                Notification notification = mBuilder.setSmallIcon(icon).setTicker(title).setWhen(0)
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(title)
                        .setStyle(inboxStyle)
                        .setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent)
                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION))
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(mContext.getResources(), icon))
                        .setContentText(message)
                        .build();

                NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notificationManager.notify(mNotificationId, notification);



        }
```

Now the problem is I get notification every night at 10pm which is fine. But after clicking on it and entering the application the notification is displayed again and again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are triggering the Local Notification every time from DrawerActivity, Save a preference that local notifications are schedule and check it before scheduling next time.

Currently everytime DrawerActivity onCreate is called the notification is triggered.